# Getting html after javascript execution WITHOUT WebView (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a project that involves a lot of html parsing. I have come across and issue that I cannot find the solution to. Basically, what I have is an application that downloads html from a website and parses it (I am using `HTMLCleaner` as my parser). However, this website contains some javascript elements, which after execution change the html. What I need to do is execute the javascript function from my application and then download the html.

I have been looking for the solution for days, but all I managed to find was how to do this using `WebView`, which in my case I do not want.

I do have an idea for solving the problem, which is making an unrendered `WebView` and using that. However, I am sure there is one better then that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been looking for the solution for days, but all I managed to find was how to do this using WebView, which in my case I do not want.

You need something that knows how to render Web pages. Nothing else is going to do what you want (create a DOM, then run JavaScript that modifies that DOM).

> I do have an idea for solving the problem, which is making an unrendered WebView and using that

That is one solution. Or, you could play around with Firefox's [GeckoView](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2013/10/geckoview-embedding-gecko-in-your-android-application/), which will do similar stuff, just with their own rendering engine.

> However, I am sure there is one better then that.

You can build your own Web browser from scratch.

Comment: What about HTML parsers? I've done everything using HTMLCleaner until this point. Is there an alternative parser that can get the data after a javascript execution?

Comment: HTML parser will parse static HTML, but won't execute JS.